# How to ping a PC on a different subnet?

Tags: lan

sorry if this is not exactly a "programming" question! I have two PCs on a LAN, connected to two different subnets: one on 192.168.95.x and the other on 192.168.200.y. I have DHCP enabled and if I ping one of the two with PC name, the DNS resolves the IP address correctly for both. However, the ping fails with request timed out every time. I expected that with DHCP enabled both PC should be able to communicate without problem, but apparently not? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried pinging with the firewall off on both PC's? Are the PC's able to ping their default gateway? How far does a trace route come?

Comment: probably in https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ you could get better answers

Comment: Hello all, yes the firewall is configured to allow connections from within the LAN, so it shouldn't be a problem. The PCs can ping their respective default gateway. Tracert is stuck from the first hop!

Answer (score 0):

1 - Try doing it with firewalls off on both devices

2 - Try do a tracert (if these are Windows Machines) from one PC to another.

3 - You need to set up routing between the subnets, did you check this?

4 - Did you troubleshoot the switches they are connected to?

Comment: Hello Kahn, thanks! So: 1 - firewall is configured to allow connections coming from inside the Lan, 2 - tracert stops at the first hop 3 - I tried changing some settings in the IPv4 connection, however this simply causes the pc to lose access to the internet and Lan. 4- switches work fine, cause we have shared servers to store files (on their own subnets) and both pc can connect to those with no problems

Comment: If your tracert is stuck from the first hop, it will mean that the PC's can't go further than their default gateway (i assume). Your problem is most surely ROUTING-related. 

Post us your config of the routers or give us more information so that we can help